# Customized landing page, can we disable it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed recently, that near all new Questions on the landingpage for SO are related to `PHP` and `HTML` for me.

Personaly, yes i can answer this kind of Question best, because i have experience in Webdevelopment since more then 10 years. But my current interest is more or less `C#`. If i registered to SO, i have seen many Questions about different topics. I thought, this is nice, you can learn about different languages and see the specific problems of it. I can not answer most of them, but it is still interessting for reading.

Now if i visit stackoverflow, i only see `PHP` problems, and most of them, i think [RTFM](https://www.google.com/search?q=rtfm) or at least [LMGTFY](http://lmgtfy.com/), which would be a `PHP` related problem.

Sure I want to answer good PHP Question in the next time, but i also want to see more than `PHP`. Sure i can go to featured tab, but this kind of questions is more for very specific problems (Why is this compiler work different to another?), which are a level to high for me.

Is there a possibilty to disable customized questions?

---

From the comments i see, there is not such a function on SO. Would this be a good feature?

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me, what should be your actual _'personal landing page'_?

Comment: i mean the main page for new question. The pure stackoverflow.com page, if you click on the stackoverflow branding (No subpage)

Comment: Ah, I thought you were talking about answering questions appearing on a particularly filtered queue.

Comment: Doesn't completely answer your question, but if you add C# to your favorite tags, you should start seeing lots of C# questions on the front page.

Comment: @Troyen thanks for your suggestion. It is a good point, would help to see the question for the language, i currently work with. But nice would be, to see something from all, so i am not only a "Nerd/Geek" (Pretty sure dict.cc has a wrong translation for german word "Fachidiot";))

Comment: As we both talk german: "Ich habe keine Ahnung wonach Du hier fragst :-/ ... Geht's um die Vorschläge, die Du beim Erstellen einer neuen Frage erhältst?"

Comment: No. It's about the new questions when I'm on the start page of StackOverflow. I want to not only get PHP questions. I want to see more, than my main topic, like it is if I had a new account on SO. ### Nein. Es geht um die neuen Fragen, wenn ich auf der Startseite von Stackoverflow bin. Ich möchte nicht nur PHP Fragen erhalten, sondern Quer Beet alle Fragen. Ich möchte sozusagen über den Tellerrand hinausschauen ;) Also wie es ist, wenn ich einen neuen Account auf SO hätte.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt OK got it, let's switch back to english to enable others participating. When I'm going to `my startpage` I usually use the [c++ filtered queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), but I have several other favorite tags as well. Questions that apply for more than one additional on top of the [tag_c++] tag will be highlighted. Though if I wan't to have a different view for recent questions, I'll need to change my primary filtering tag. If you want to look more _over the Tellerand_ you may consider to work on the [review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: This filtered queue would by a good work arround for me. thanks. Nice to have would be, to do it without self defined filter, so i don't need to check, which tags would be interessting for me (potentially every tag, because i want to learn about every technology, maybe not so much, but at least it is there). So i think this feature is not availibe. I edit the Question and add the a feature request tag.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt You can apply multiple tag filters like these [`[c++][singleton]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20singleton) of course, but if you're in work flow you might have to want a _one click link_ for this favorite tag combination. That's actually only available by saving your personally preferred bookmarks in your browser, and have these at hand IMHO.